# Is there simple url builder for applet?

Tags: java, url, parameters, applet

I want to convert from array into get-parameters of URL.
I know HTTPClient of apache, but it's too large for applet.

is there simple solution?

I have a List(or array) in my applet, and I want to write URL-parameters for HttpRequest.
ParameterFormatter is good, but the jar file is too large for applet.

edit:
I found there is Java Optimizer/Shrinker/Reducer tool allows you to optimize jar. eg proguard

Comment: Kindly explain more or give an example of what you want to achieve. Thanks :)

Comment: I want such org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.ParameterFormatter.format(). but the jar file is too large for applet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply develop one yourself as you only need to join them together to a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). I'm doing some assumptions on what you want (such as the key for each variable starts with `var`) but here goes:

```
public String buildUrl(String baseUrl, String[] getVars) {

    String url = baseUrl + "?";
    // Builds: http://mydomain.com/app?

    for (int i = 0; i < getVars.length; i++) {

        url += "var" + i + "=" + getVars[i];
        // Builds the query string, ...app?var1=lol

        if (i < getVars.length - 1) {

            url += "&";
            // Adds the & after each var except for the last one
            // ...app?var1=lol&
        }

        // repeat for each var until done
        // ... app?var1=lol&var2=cat
    }

    return url;

}
```

There are of course other naïve implementations and optimizations to the code that you can do. There also might be some Java class that does this already, but it seems that you have to [build it on your own](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/BuildquerystringforURL.htm) or use the Apache Commons 3rd party library (which I understand you can't).

Comment: Oh! thank you! I thought there is also other solution by split jar.

Comment: Btw. don't forget to wrap the values with `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(…)` to fix the cases where the value contains characters that can break the URL or the query string. I let that solution be an exercise for the reader (as it requires exception handling).